# Make webpack move files from src to dest without processing it

Tags: javascript, jsf, webpack

I have some sites running with JSF and some vanilla ES6 that is being processed with webpack (Running 4.6).

The problem is that webpack adds something to my jsf.js file when it moves the file to my dest folder, and doesn't work with how JSF needs to be run.

Setup: There is the jsf.js and the vanilla ES6 files in a src folder. I then use webpack to process and move the bundle and the jsf.js file to a dest folder.

The JSF.js file is already minimized in the src folder and cannot be uglified so I have added exclude on uglify:

```
 optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        exclude: /(jsf.js)/,
      })
    ]
  }
```

The jsf.js also has its own entry btw.

So my question is, how do I make webpack *only* move the jsf.js and add nothing to it? There must be some kind of exclude that I am missing here. I use no plugins other than uglify.

Comment: can you provide  more detailed webpack configurations ? Since you do not want webpack process jsf.js, why it has its own entry?

Comment: The only reason why I have an entry for it is to move it to the dest folder - I wanted webpack to handle all the js files and not have to rely on some other npm script or gulp/grunt to move it. But maybe I am "miss using" it that way.  

Basically what I need is for webpack to only copy the file to dest.

There isn't much more to add about the configuration - it has 'standard' entry, output and a single rule for the babel-loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want copy jsf.js to dist directory. you should try [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin), not give it its own entry.

install it throught npm:

```
npm i -D copy-webpack-plugin
```

require it in webpack.config.js

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
```

add to plugins's array

```
[
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'path/to/jsf.js', to: 'dist/' }
  ])
]
```

Comment: But ofc, didn't think of it as a static file like that, but I guess it kinda is - so the copy plugin is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined" when i do this ... any idea?